# Nested Flatten in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have problem using Pig Like this:
Suppose I have a alias A, like ("key1","just_for_example"). I want something like :("key1","just"),("key1","for"),("key1","example"). My script looks like:

B = foreach A generate $0, FLATTEN(TOBAG(FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($1,'_'))));

But it keeps throwing me errors like "Error 1070:Couldn't resolve Flatten from builtin". But once I split this statement into two to eliminate the nested flattens, then it works. Why is that? Is it related to how Pig compile my script? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten is not a UDF, it is an operator that changes the format of bags and tuples.  You can read the description [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#flatten).

You can get the desired output in a clean one-liner though. TOKENIZE works similarly to STRSPLIT, but produces a bag instead of a tuple.  Therefore, you can just do:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE($1, '_')) ;
```

Resulting schema and output:

```
B: {key: chararray,bag_of_tokenTuples::token: chararray}
(key1,just)
(key1,for)
(key1,example)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten is not a function - you can't nest it.

However, in your case, I don't think you have to use it twice. This should suffice to get your desired output:

```
B = foreach A generate $0, FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($1,'_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate you question, Please find my solution below. have taken flatten_exe.txt as an input which contains data as ("Just_For_example")

```
grunt> flt= Load '/home/training/pig/Join/flatten_exe.txt' using PigStorage();

grunt> b= Foreach flt Generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE($0, '_'));  

grunt>dump b;
```